# nginx rewrite filename remove part of the name

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I can't seem to figure out this nginx url rewrite.

This is what I need

Url looks like this:

/manager/

/manager/dashboard

/manager/session

/manager/view

These map to, in order:

/manager/index__cms.php

/manager/index__cms.php

/manager/dashboard__cms.php

/manager/session__cms.php

/manager/view__cms.php

ALSO:

/manager/js/module - map to - /manager/js/module_js.php

/manager/js/index - map to - /manager/js/index_js.php

I would rename the files but the previous programmer mapped everything out using these url mappings. And the program was previously on apache, now nginx.

What I currently have is:

```
location /manager {
index index__cms.php;
rewrite ^(.*)\__cms.php break;
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

I did the following. It's not pretty but it works.

```
location /manager {index index__cms.php; try_files $uri $uri/ /manager/index__cms.php$is_args$args;}
location /manager/dashboard {try_files $uri $uri/ /manager/index__cms.php$is_args$args;}
location /manager/session {try_files $uri $uri/ /manager/session__cms.php$is_args$args;}
```

There was 20 some odd files and it was just easier then making a dynamic method. The code that needs this is getting retired in the near future so it doesn't need to be pretty as it will get deleted along with the config supporting it.

Comment: Cool story, bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
map $uri $remapped_uri {
    default                 $uri;
    ~^/manager/([^/]+)$     /manager/$1__cms.php;
    ~^/manager/js/([^/]+)$  /manager/js/$1_js.php;
}

server {
    ...
    location /manager/ {
        index index__cms.php;
        rewrite .* $remapped_uri last;
    }
}
```

But is it correct that request for `yourdomain.com/manager/js/` will go to `yourdomain.com/manager/js/index__cms.php`? If it is not, and correct index file for `yourdomain.com/manager/js/` is `index_js.php`, here is another example:

```
map $uri $remapped_uri {
    default                 $uri;
    /manager/               /manager/index__cms.php;
    ~^/manager/([^/]+)$     /manager/$1__cms.php;
    /manager/js/            /manager/js/index_js.php;
    ~^/manager/js/([^/]+)$  /manager/js/$1_js.php;
}

server {
    ...
    location /manager/ {
        rewrite .* $remapped_uri last;
    }
}
```

To serve `/manager`, `/manager/js` as `/manager/`, `/manager/js/`:

```
map $uri $remapped_uri {
    default                 $uri;
    ~^/manager/?$           /manager/index__cms.php;
    ~^/manager/([^/]+)$     /manager/$1__cms.php;
    ~^/manager/js/?$        /manager/js/index_js.php;
    ~^/manager/js/([^/]+)$  /manager/js/$1_js.php;
}

server {
    ...
    location /manager {
        rewrite .* $remapped_uri last;
    }
}
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527) answer.

Comment: Ivan, thanks! I tried your method but I just couldn't get it to work. Likely due to my other configs. Regardless I still accept it as the answer that solves this. I updated my post to reflect what I did instead.

Comment: @Alan Thank you, but I don't think it is correct to accept an answer that does not solve a problem, it may confusing other people. Anyway, I tested my config on a real server, and found a mistake. I used a `break` flag on a `rewrite` directive instead of `last`. With this flag php script will not pass through php interpreter. Can you test an updated config, please?